# How to create sockets in google chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I created small hello world extension for google chrome http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html. I need to use sockets in extension for peer to peer communication using UDP. Is there any firefox [Jslib](http://jslib.mozdev.org/installation.html) equivalent in google chrome or how we can use other languages in google chrome extension?

I doubt its possible in google chrome, looking at its [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/index.html). ? Are there any other ways to achieve p2p communication in extension?

Answer (score 6):

Chrome has an packaged app support for [raw socket connections](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html). More general info [here](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app_network.html). This used to be available to extensions as well but it's not clear if that's still true.

The documentation indicates that only **UDP** is available for the type when the socket is created. However, recently (Jan 2012) there was a [commit adding TCP support](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110465).

Comment: @jnnnnn, yes, they seem to move it around a lot. I've update the link to an packaged app version of the link. It may still be available for extensions but it's not clear.

Comment: @kanaka, Is this possible in Chrome extensions? The API you linked to is for Chrome Apps.

Answer (score 4):

These are not websockets (it's TCP or UDP sockets):

http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html

https://developers.google.com/live/shows/7320022-5001

The second link is a howto for making a web-server in a Chrome app.