# Connecting chrome extension to an sql database

Tags: sql, database, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension. I want to connect my extension to an SQL database on my computer. Which are the possible and efficient ways I can do this?

Comment: 1) configure web access on localhost in your database and access it from your extension using [XHR/fetch](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr), 2) find or write a separate utility (in node.js or any other language) that accesses the database directly and communicates with your extension via [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to DB from a Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769081/connecting-to-db-from-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: yes but answers there is all about AJAX. I want to know all different methods, that can be used.

Comment: Since chrome extensions support [raw tcp sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1535752/1048572), it should be possible to connect. You'll probably have to rewrite the network part of a node.js library, though